# Robot Framework FOR loop giving error as Variable ${i} not found

Tags: robotframework

I an executing a simple FOR loop in robot framework. but I am getting the variable not found error.

I am executing below code.

```
    *** Test Cases ***
ForLoop1
    FOR   ${i}    IN RANGE    1   10
        Log to console  ${i}

    END
```

I am getting below error in terminal

```
    (venv) C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\RF_Automation\TestCases> robot FOrLoop.robot
c:\users\hp\python38-32\lib\runpy.py:126: RuntimeWarning: 'robot.run' found in sys.modules after import of package 'robot', but prior to execution of 'robot.run'
; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
==============================================================================
FOrLoop
==============================================================================
ForLoop1                                                              | FAIL |
Variable '${i}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOrLoop                                                               | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

Comment: When I fix the indentation on the first line, your test works just fine for me with both robot 3.1 and 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same error and I found that the keyword "FOR" was written "For" so not recognized as a keyword and thus the "Log to console" statement was trying to print an unknown variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax instead

```
: FOR    ${client}    IN    @{clients}
\    Log    ${client}
```